# Wordpress on Google cloud mysql connection trouble

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I am having a wordpress instance on my google cloud and mysql instance on google cloud sql , Now I can't update or edit a post or it is too slow because there is a big delay on getting response from the mysql , especially searching on the media files 
How can I rectify this error ?

Comment: Can you provide more details from the error it self ?

Comment: There is errors coming out but the ajax request from admin panel never get completed and shows  a connection lost message on wordpress

Comment: If possible, please include the snippet code and the error that coming out because your ajax request...